# Manually adding days to date?

Tags: java, date, methods

example of output should be like this: 
Input days : 1 
Input months: 1 
Input Year : 2012 
Input AddedDays : 61 
Assuming February is (29days for every year)
then output : 1-March-2012; 
but instead i got 0-March-2012
my Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NO3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Input days : ");
        int days = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input month : ");
        int month = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input year : ");
        int year = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Input added days : ");
        int addeddays = sc.nextInt();



        System.out.print("Output : ");
        System.out.print(add(days,month,year,addeddays));
    }

    public static int add(int days,int month,int year,int addeddays)
    {
        int countermonth=0;


        if(month==1)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=31)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
        else if(month==2)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=29)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/29;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*29);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
        else if(month==3)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=31)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }
        else if(month==4)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=30)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/30;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*30);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==5)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=31)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==6)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=30)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/30;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*30);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==7)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=31)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==8)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=31)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==9)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=30)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/30;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*30);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==10)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=31)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==11)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=30)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/30;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*30);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        else if(month==12)
        {
            if(days+addeddays>=31)
            {
                countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
                month += countermonth;
                days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
                System.out.print(days);
                System.out.print("-");
            }
        }

        if(month>12)
                {
                   int counteryear = month/12;
                   month = month - (counteryear*12);
                   year +=counteryear;
                }

                if(month==1)
                {
                    System.out.print("January");
                }
                else if(month==2)
                {
                    System.out.print("February");
                }
                else if(month==3)
                {
                    System.out.print("March");
                }
                else if(month==4)
                {
                    System.out.print("April");
                }
                 else if(month==5)
                {
                    System.out.print("May");
                }
                else if(month==6)
                {
                    System.out.print("June");
                }
                else if(month==7)
                {
                    System.out.print("July");
                }
                else if(month==8)
                {
                    System.out.print("August");
                }
                else if(month==9)
                {
                    System.out.print("September");
                }
                else if(month==10)
                {
                    System.out.print("October");
                }
                else if(month==11)
                {
                    System.out.print("November");
                }
                else if(month==12)
                {
                    System.out.print("December");
                }
                System.out.print("-");
                //System.out.println("");

        return year;
    }

}
```

Im stil learning java so i know its very inefficient so can anyone show me or teach me the correct yet efficient solution? (this question asked to use method only and no java class like date) Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to perform your date arithmetic. Something like,

```
public static Date add(int days, int month, int year, int addeddays) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, days);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, addeddays);
    return c.getTime();
}
```

Then you can use a [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format it. Something like,

```
System.out.print("Output : ");
Date d = add(days, month, year, addeddays);
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d-MMMM-yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(d));
```

Of course, with your provided inputs, you'll get

```
Output : 2-March-2012
```

Because there were 31 days in January, 29 days in February (for a *total* of 60 days). Adding 61 days thus results in March 2nd.

Comment: lets say if i have to do it without java calendar , using only method how can i fix my code? Thanks @Elliott Frisch

Comment: @MisterV Use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are more efficient ways to do that, java has Classes for Date Manipulation.. Just take a look to [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) and [Java.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).
So, one alternative can be:
Create a Date object with the input,

```
String input = "05.05.2015";
int addedDays = "61;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Calendar calendarFrom = Calendar.getInstance();

calendarFrom.setTime(dateFormat.parse(s1));
calendarFrom.add(Calendar.DATE, addedDays);
```

and there you are!

Comment: Thanks but what if the question specifically asked not to use java date classes?is there any other way? @jipr311

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know the issue:

```
countermonth = (days+addeddays)/31;
            month += countermonth;
            days = days+addeddays - (countermonth*31);
```

days become zero, since it's like`(countermonth*31=days+addeddays).`

hope it helps.